# Simple chair anatomy? Do most people call it "the chair face"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, nouns

This question is about "**Simple chair anatomy?**"

Most people know what are "**the legs or the back of the chair**"

I found this picture on the internet

[image]

Look at the picture on the right. They call it "**the face of the chair**" which is the part of the chair that people sit on.

My question is that:

is "**the face of the chair**" a common term just like its counterparts "**the legs or the back of the chair**"?

Most people say "**the legs or the back of the chair**" but I haven't heard "**the face of the chair**"?

Could we say "**Do not put your feet on the face of the chair**"?

Comment: I wonder if that pick-up line is somehow related to this: *I wish I was a Chair so you could sit on my face!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could we say "**Do not put your feet on the face of the chair**"?

We could, but no one would know what we were talking about. The part of a chair that we sit on is called the seat, as your left-hand drawing indicates.

The clue here is the source of your right-hand drawing. Notice that at the bottom are the words "I am Prikle." This is the title of a series of on-line comic strips, apparently now defunct (although the google will still find images upon request). Because it's a comic strip, it's references are supposed to be humorous and are not to be taken seriously. In fact, this particular "joke" may be intended as slightly off-color, but I'm far too old to either understand or be amused by online anything.

The only thing harder than properly understanding humorous language is spotting it in the first place.

By the way, *Rowan* is a line of chairs, and the title "Anatomy of  Rowan" plays on the fact that  many parts of chairs share names with body parts.

Comment: +1 Very well explained. I wonder if the chair's face was/is a thing. This brings to mind the raunchy pick-up line: *I wish I was a chair so you could sit on my face!*

Comment: @AIQ Oh, good. I was worried that I had the only mind that brings up the raunchy.

Comment: My native is Vietnamese & we call it "the face of the chair" (translated words-for-words from Vietnamese)

Answer (score 2):

The part of the chair on which you sit is almost exclusively called the seat of the chair. Calling it the face of the chair is highly unusual - this is the first I have heard it. Most English speakers would be unlikely to immediately understand what was meant if it was referred to as the face.

Wikipedia's article on chairs has a section devoted to chair seats. In the article it is only referred to as the seat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chair#Seats

Answer (score 1):

The part of a chair, a stool, or an armchair on which you seat is called a **seat**. A **seat** is the part you seat on because you seat on it. There isn't any part of a chair that is referred to as "**the face**".